# Why is it slower to initiate a jQuery POST request with a binary image vs its Base64-encoded equivalent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, post, image-processing

We need to send image data to a server from a web client.

Originally, we used JSON to POST the data and Base64 encoded the image. This increased the image size by 33%.

Sending the same image data in binary takes *more* time for the request to initiate even though the image size is smaller.

To reiterate, this isn't about the full request time, but the time it takes jQuery to *start* the request. (See the Chrome network breakdown, the *Request sent* time.)

Why is this?

How can you accelerate a jQuery POST operation of binary image data?

jQuery:

```
// Create request form.
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', imageFile);
formData.append('requestId', '28682');

// Set request settings.
let settings = {
    url: serverUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    timeout: 0,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formData,
    xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (xhr.readyState == 2) {
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
                } else {
                  xhr.responseType = 'text';
                }
           }
        };
        return xhr;
    },
};
```

Request Timing (as reported by Chrome):

[image]

Comment: `Sending the same image data in binary takes more time for the request to get sent even though the image size is smaller.` ... likely a conversion takes place even if you are not aware of it. Blackbox magic

Comment: @GetSet could you elaborate? To clarify, the question is about cutting down the 7+ seconds to send the request, not about server processing.